# Spring caching issues when using AspectJ LTW

Tags: java, spring, caching, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I'm using cache abstraction mechanism from Spring 3.0 RC1 : I've set up bytecode (based on AspectJ) weawing so that cache mechanism can be applied to methods called from within the class itself.
It is worth saying that first I was using proxy-based approach : everything was working fine (for methods are invoked from another object.)

As soon as I switch to AspectJ (I activated LTW via , added the right jars into their place - everything is working fine, no exceptions are thrown),no caching takes place

Any suggestion? Thank you.

**==== later edit ========**

I set up the logs to DEBUG for org.springframework.

If using proxy mode, I can clearly see the message Adding cacheable method 'getLargeAssetContent'.... where getLargeAssetContent is my "cacheable" method...(please see bellow)

If using aspectj mode, I don't see this message....every requests goes to the DAO layer...where as, in situation where cache works, requests stop at service layer.

What I am doing wrong? Do I need an aop.xml? I was not using AOP...., so I don't have yet an aop.xml.

Thank you for your help.

*> *2011-12-12 16:38:55,998 DEBUG [org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource]

> (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Adding cacheable method 'getLargeAssetContent'
>   with attribute: [CacheOperation[public
>   com.mycompany.myprj.model.AssetContent
>   com.mycompany.myprj.dao.jcr.AssetDAOImpl.getLargeAssetContent(java.lang.String)
>   throws com.mycompany.myprj.dao.MyPrjPersistenceException]
>   caches=[assets] | condition='' | key='#nodeId'] 2011-12-12
>   16:38:56,013 INFO  [com.mycompany.myprj.dao.jcr.AssetDAOImpl]
>   (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Getting the content (getLargeAssetContent) of
>   asset from node with id=575d8dc0-01be-41e4-85ce-a654fab97fe8
>   2011-12-12 16:38:56,092 INFO 
>   [com.mycompany.myprj.dao.jcr.AssetDAOImpl] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6)
>   Returning the content of asset from node with
>   id=575d8dc0-01be-41e4-85ce-a654fab97fe8**

*

> //the content is cached by now 2011-12-12 16:38:57,654 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]
>   (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Returning cached instance of singleton bean
>   'assetController' 2011-12-12 16:38:57,654 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]
>   (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Last-Modified value for
>   [/myprj/asset/get/575d8dc0-01be-41e4-85ce-a654fab97fe8] is: -1
>   2011-12-12 16:38:57,654 INFO 
>   [com.mycompany.myprj.services.AssetService] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6)
>   Getting asset with id: 57

*

Comment: When you said enabled LTW, you added `<context:load-time-weaver/>` in your context, right?

Comment: I'm facing e=the exact same problem. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: So do I, still not able to have it done with LTW. Fall back to proxy mode for now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure AspectJ mode is enabled (see [*28.3.3 Enable caching annotations*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable)):

```
<cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

By default caching abstraction uses `proxy` mode, despite having LTW enabled (should switch automatically to `aspectj` IMHO, but it doesn't).

If this does not help examine stack trace when calling cached method from outside and from inside - what are the differences?

Comment: Thanks, but I did that (<cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />) . I'll try to look to the traces.

Comment: Just of curiosity, did someone managed to get this thing working? (i.e. using caching abstraction with aspectj)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with a sample project and needed to do the following to switch from regular proxy to aspectj LTW

- Change `<cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>`
- Add aspectj-weaver and spring-aspects to the classpath (easy to identify in face of the ClassNotFoundException thrown)
- Have a default aop.xml in a META-INF/aop.xml (this one is with default settings and configuration to proxy classes in my specific package - otherwise it will proxy classes in the entire JVM - which you need to take a call on)
- Add `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>` (Default is autodetect which will silently fail if META-INF/aop.xml is not found)
- Add the `javaagent` switch the VM and point it to the spring-instrument jar if you are using it standalone. If you are in a container you can either use the javaagent or have it configured to a specific classloader as mentioned in the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments).